# 2nd report on Joint Tahzoo, should be Join Tahzoo

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

See image of joint Tahzoo

[image]

Sorry I cannot report it via the job listing page because I'm on mobile and it doesn't seem to work on mobile.

Please remove the t in joint.

Comment: Maybe that job is only for psychedelic developers?